# how do i ger the Autorization code from linkedin API

Tags: linkedin-api

how do i get the Authentication code, i am using below link to get this
"https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=" + apiKey + "&redirect_uri=" + REDIRECT_URL + "&state=" + STATE + "&scope=w_share";

but it keep asking me to click on Allow button, is there any way i can automate this programatically.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it.

If you could do it automatically **without user interaction**, it would mean that your application can manipulate the user's data freely without getting approval from the user.